# How to write myDel with append in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, append

I'm new to Prolog and stuck on some programming homework. one of them should work like this:

```
myDel(1, [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4], M).
```

the result should be:

```
M = [2, 3, 4].
```

to solve this, one can **only use append** recursively and can **not use the built-in delete**.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say that it's quite difficult to help without just spoon-feeding you the answer. Prolog is a bit like that. Here's a partial answer that hopefully doesn't give too much away:

```
myDel(N, [], []).
myDel(N, [N|T], U) :- ...
```

Comment: Think about what relationship T and U must have for the answer to be valid and how you would express this in the body of the second clause. Also consider the need for a third clause that covers the case where the head of the second list doesn't equal N (`myDel(N, [H|T], ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Cut was needed.

```
myDel(N,L,DelL) :-
   append(L0,[N|R],L),
   myDel(N,R,DelL2),
   append(L0,DelL2,DelL),
   !.
myDel(_,L,L).
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!! but marcelo comes first and enlights me earlier:)